# in range loop skipping through

Tags: python, loops, range

```
    salary=0
salaryArray=[]
loop=0
noYears=int(input("How many years do you want to do salaries for? "))
for i in range(0,noYears):
    while loop==0:
        print()
        print("You can add multiple sources of income, one at a time")
        salaryType=input("Do you want to put in your salary hourly or yearly? (h/y) ")
        if salaryType=="y":
            salarySection=float(input("What is your salary? "))
            salary=salarySection+salary
        else:
            salaryHourly=float(input("What are you payed per hour? "))
            salaryWeekly=float(input("How many hours per week will you work? "))
            salaryYearly=float(input("How many weeks per year will you work? "))
            print()
            salarySection=salaryHourly*salaryWeekly*salaryYearly
            salary=salary+salarySection
        
        repeat=input("Do you wish to add another source of income? (y/n) ")
        if repeat=="n":
            print("This year's anual salary is", salary)
            salaryArray.append(salary)
            loop=1
```

For some reason the `for i in range(0,noYears)` isn't working?
It just moves on to the next line of code after doing it through once - even though I put the answer to noYears as 3.

Anyone know why this might be as I cannot see what is wrong?
:)

Comment: please strip down your code to the bare minimum needed to reproduce your question. (e.g. remove all the `input` statements)

Comment: The for loop is working. It's the while loop that is skipped, because `loop` is still 1.

Comment: It might be helpful to include example input/output and how the output is different from what you expect

Comment: Set ```loop = 0``` before calling the ```while``` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't working because the while loop never executes. You could solve this two ways.

1. Use a break statement instead of setting loop to 1:

   ```
    #previous code

    repeat=input("Do you wish to add another source of income? (y/n) ")
    if repeat=="n":
        print("This year's anual salary is", salary)
        salaryArray.append(salary)
        break
   ```
2. Reset the variable loop to 0 inside of the for loop:

   ```
    for i in range(0,noYears):
        loop = 0 
        while loop==0:
        # remaining code
   ```